# DashboardViewer PivotDashboardItem PivotGridControl Drag Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, dashboard, devexpress-windows-ui

i would like to explain my circumstance briefly,
I use DashboardViwer item and i load xml to it onload which has been created and saved by DashboardDesigner.

Then, i fill DashboardObjectDataSource and i add it to dashboard data source to set it to items.

Finaly, i open some properties and activere customizationform for PivotGridControl which inside dashboard viewer.

i see the report result correctly acording to my design that has been created by dashboard designer.

But, when i want to change field orders or place i get this exceptions;

[Object Referance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKUPj.jpg)

```
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Data.PivotFieldCellValueItem.GetTextCore()
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Data.PivotFieldValueItem.GetCustomText(Boolean calculateIsCustomDisplayText)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Data.PivotFieldValueItem.CalculateText()
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Data.PivotFieldValueItem.get_Text()
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.Data.PivotFieldValueItem.get_DisplayText()
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.PivotFieldsAreaCellViewInfo.get_DisplayText()
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.PivotFieldsAreaCellViewInfoBase.CreateHeaderInfoArgs(GraphicsCache graphicsCache)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.PivotFieldsAreaCellViewInfoBase.InternalPaint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfo.Paint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfoCollection.Paint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfo.PaintChildren(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfo.Paint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfoCollection.Paint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfo.PaintChildren(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfo.Paint(ViewInfoPaintArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.ViewInfo.BaseViewInfoControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   position: DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   position: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

---

#### Dashboard Viewer Item data source

[C#]

```
lSales = oSales.GetReport(filter); // fill list and set default values if it is null
dashboardViewerCreation.Dashboard.DataSources.Clear();
oDashboardObjectDataSource = new DashboardObjectDataSource(dashTitle, lSales);
dashboardViewerCreation.Dashboard.DataSources.Add(oDashboardObjectDataSource);

//Control each item and set data source
foreach (DashboardItem dashboardItem in dashboardViewerCreation.Dashboard.Items)
{
    if (dashboardItem.GetType() == typeof(PivotDashboardItem))
    {
        ((PivotDashboardItem)dashboardItem).DataSource = oDashboardObjectDataSource;
    }

}

dashboardViewerCreation.ReloadData(true);
dashboardViewerCreation.Refresh();
```

#### Dashboard Viever Item events

[C#]

```
private void dashboardViewerCreation_DashboardItemControlCreated(object sender, DevExpress.DashboardWin.DashboardItemControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PivotGridControl != null)
        {
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowPrefilter = false;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowDrag = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowEdit = false;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowExpand = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowExpandOnDoubleClick = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowFilter = false;

            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowCustomizationForm = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowDragInCustomizationForm = true;

            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsBehavior.CopyToClipboardWithFieldValues = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsBehavior.ApplyBestFitOnFieldDragging = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsBehavior.HorizontalScrolling = PivotGridScrolling.Control;


            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsMenu.EnableFieldValueMenu = false;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsMenu.EnableFormatRulesMenu = false;

            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowDataHeaders = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowRowHeaders = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowFilterHeaders = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowFilterSeparatorBar = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowRowGrandTotals = true;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsView.ShowColumnTotals = true;

            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormLayout = CustomizationFormLayout.StackedDefault;
            e.PivotGridControl.OptionsCustomization.CustomizationFormStyle = CustomizationFormStyle.Excel2007;
            
            e.PivotGridControl.ShowingCustomizationForm += PivotGridControlOnShowingCustomizationForm;

        }
    }

       
private void PivotGridControlOnShowingCustomizationForm(object sender, CustomizationFormShowingEventArgs customizationFormShowingEventArgs)
    {
        customizationFormShowingEventArgs.ParentControl = splitContainerControl1.Panel1;
        customizationFormShowingEventArgs.CustomizationForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sergi (DevExpress Support);
>
> In the current version, Dashboard Pivot Grid Item does not support the
> Customization Form functionality. Therefore, if you display it
> manually using the API of the inner pivot grid control, Customization
> Form may work incorrectly, or exception will be thrown as in your
> case.
>
> Currently, it is possible to reorder dimensions and measures in Pivot
> Grid Item using the Dashboard Designer. If this approach does not meet
> your requirements, would you please describe your scenario in greater
> detail? We look forward to hearing from you.

---

> John (DevExpress Support);
>
> The DashboardViewer control was designed only to display dashboards. That's
> why there is
> no simple way to use the PivotGrid control's customization
> capabilities in DashboardViewer. To customize dashboards in the
> required manner, you would need to use the DashboardDesigner control.